# Refer to wrongly named images in Android app

Tags: android, android-glide

Is there any possibility to refer to wrongly named images in Android? I have bunch of images that have wrong names, for example `IMG123456.jpg` (u. c.), `1_img.jpg` (number first) etc. It would be really hard to rename them all, cause I have `JSON` file that I load and there are also these names.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to store these image files anywhere?
2. Is it possible to refer to these images with `Glide` library?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You can name an image file whatever you want, and then just reference it by calling the name that you set for it. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can't, obviously put file named `1_img.jpg` into drawable folder, cause I get error: `The resource name must start with a letter`. Maybe my question is obvious for somebody, but if I put my files into for example `raw/images` folder, then I can't refer to and display them. I've been thinking about assets folder, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe I think, I solved my problem, but thanks for effort.

Comment: I don't think that's obvious at all, and it would be better to explain the real issue in the question (which is that resource files must begin with a letter, and your files don't meet that requirement) rather than hope that someone will be able to read your mind and know what you really meant. Regardless, it wouldn't be too difficult to write a small bit of code that could batch rename the files for you to something usable.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that `assets` folder should have path like this: `src\main\assets`. To refer to images with `Glide` in assets folder it's needed to do that like this:

```
.load("file:///android_asset/images/1_img.jpg")
```

It's very important to remember about the extension!